# How to read and write to .txt in layer properties, action tab?

Tags: qgis, windows, actions

I want to write a certain attribute to a .txt file using the action tab in the layer properties (combined with Hotlink).

In the QGIS-2.2-UserGuide, on page 97, there is an example on how to do that in Linux (see image). 
What is the correct alteration of this for it to work in Windows?

[image]